# Play video as background in iPad App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video

I have an app and it has a static uimage as the background. To dress up the app, I have a video that would be great as the background but I cannot find any examples of how to play a video as a background view.  I have looked at MPMoviePlayerController but I am not sure if it would do what I am expecting.

Anyone have any ideas, or an example of a video as a background to an app?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could just use the MPMoviePlayerController, if you don't do it fullscreen (which is not possible on the iPhone, but it is so on the iPad).
Then you can just put buttons, labels whatever you want on top of that.
Should work fine :)

Comment: Yes, noone offered any suggestions, so I guess it is not a very popular thing to do.  But in any event, that is exactly what I did and it looks GREAT!!!.. i basically made my video 1024x768 in both orientations, made the vid full screen and I hide the controls.  Works awesome.  Thanks for the comment!!